# Target and do actions in each Div instead of one specific div

Tags: jquery

I have severals `divs` generated by php with differents contenst inside, and for each of theses `divs` there are several comments.

Inside each of theses divs, aswell as inside each comments, I am using jquery to display/hide more content, or animate things, and even upvote/downvote comments.

I know how to tell JQuery to do things on a targeted div, like :

```
   $('#div1').hover( function() {
        $("#div1").toggleClass("class1");
   } );
```

but I've never done it on several divs (which also have the same class names) at the same time.

To be more specific, I'd like to understand how I can tell JQuery to target each generated divs instead of a specific one, and do things inside them (without interferring with the others div which have the exact same class names since generated with php).

I hope I'm clear enough, I've never been that deep with JQuery yet and have troubles figuring out the right vocabulary for this request.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You should assign a specific classname to the divs being generated and bind a hover event on those elements. This however only works if the elements already exist in the DOM while the event is being registered.

```
$('div.someClassName').hover(function()
{
   $(this).toggleClass("class1");
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/5zWad/78/

If you dynamically generating the elements, then you need to switch from `hover` binding to `mouseover` `mouseover` event delegation on the document ( since hover can only be binded, not delegated )

```
$(document).on('mouseover mouseout','.someClassName',function()
  {
    $(this).toggleClass('class1');
  });
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/5zWad/79/

If you wish to target all div irrespect of the class name :

```
$('div').hover(function()
{
  $(this).toggleClass('class1');
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/5zWad/80/

If you wish to target element with more than one class

```
$('div.someClassName, div.someClassName2').hover(function()
{
  $(this).toggleClass('class1');
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/5zWad/81/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so $(this) allows me to target the same div without interfering with other div that may have the same class name is that right ? However how would I proceed if, for exemple, class1 has to be toggled on a different div than `div.someClassName` ? Like its parent-div, or another child div

Comment: Your first statement is correct. $(this) would only target the element which invokes the event. If you want to target all divs, then just use element select . $('div').hover(function() . Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/5zWad/80/

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating HTML via Ajax with PHP, you don't need to worry about them inheriting the events directly since jQuery only binds events to the selected elements currently in the DOM, unless delegated. Additionally, you'll want to target the current element that triggered the event with $(this). Since it's suggested not to reuse IDs, I'd go with a class:

```
$('.hover-this').on('mouseover mouseout', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('class1');
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/daerik/pen/mOmWPr)

Comment: You also need 'mouseout' event if you are planning to replace hover with mouseover

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've switched to class instead of ID. However how is 'mouseover mouseout' different from the 'hover' I am using ?

Comment: @eloism by using on() instead of hover() you'll be able to delegate the event to element not presently in the DOM. Please read http://api.jquery.com/on/ for more information on delegation.